# sudo /script.py - read out temperature&humidty in .php

Tags: temperature

I'm currently on a project with my Raspberry Pi B+.
I'm using a DHT22 - Temperature & Humidity Sensor. I'm also using Adafruit that's working together with python.

My Problem is, that I don't really know, how to read out a specific thing in my .php script that I want to implement in a index.php (Apache-Server).

I can read the Temperature & Humidity over putty with:

```
sudo /root/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/AdafruitDHT.py 22 4
```

while `22` is the DHT "22" Sensor - since there is an older one named "11" and `4` the GPIO of the raspberry.

putty is now telling this:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# sudo /root/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/AdafruitDHT.py 22 4
Temp=21.3*  Humidity=41.6%
```

The AdafruitDHT.py for itself looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Copyright (c) 2014 Adafruit Industries
# Author: Tony DiCola

# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
# copies or substantial portions of the Software.

# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
# SOFTWARE.
import sys

import Adafruit_DHT


# Parse command line parameters.
sensor_args = { '11': Adafruit_DHT.DHT11,
                '22': Adafruit_DHT.DHT22,
                '2302': Adafruit_DHT.AM2302 }
if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1] in sensor_args:
    sensor = sensor_args[sys.argv[1]]
    pin = sys.argv[2]
else:
    print('usage: sudo ./Adafruit_DHT.py [11|22|2302] GPIOpin#')
    print('example: sudo ./Adafruit_DHT.py 2302 4 - Read from an AM2302 connected to GPIO #4')
    sys.exit(1)

# Try to grab a sensor reading.  Use the read_retry method which will retry up
# to 15 times to get a sensor reading (waiting 2 seconds between each retry).
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)

# Un-comment the line below to convert the temperature to Fahrenheit.
# temperature = temperature * 9/5.0 + 32

# Note that sometimes you won't get a reading and
# the results will be null (because Linux can't
# guarantee the timing of calls to read the sensor).
# If this happens try again!
if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
    print('Temp={0:0.1f}*  Humidity={1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity))
else:
    print('Failed to get reading. Try again!')
    sys.exit(1)
```

my .php looks like this:

```
<?php

$temp = exec('cat /root/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/AdafruitDHT.py |grep Temp=');
$temp = explode('Temp=',$temp);
$temp = round($temp,2);

echo $temp;
?>
```

I know that my first line is not correct like that.
But I don't know how to read out the live-temperature and live-Humidity. And I didn't know what to google for exactly.

**edit 1:**

[image: With my current .php file the result looks like this]

with the following .php file, the site looks like this:

`
[image: Click me for the .php result]

as you can see, it is only missing the output coming from the DHT22-sensor only.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
cat /root/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/AdafruitDHT.py | grep Temp=
```

you are not running/executing the AdafruitDHT.py program, you are copying it contents (ie. the python program text) So what you will get back from the PHP `exec` is probably the matching line

print('Temp={0:0.1f}*  Humidity={1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity))

Change that line to:

```
$temp = exec('python /root/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/AdafruitDHT.py | grep Temp=')
```

after making sure you are allowed to use a pipe (`|`) in a PHP `exec` call. (If not consider stripping the output of the script to only that what you want to have in PHP, dropping the `| grep ....` part).

Comment: okay, I got this with the `cat` now. It is not that what i need.
I just edited my first post, so you can see how it looks.

Yes, you got it right, i want to read out the result of the script i want to execute.

When I run the `.py`script, I need to put the parameters behind it.

I tried this now:

`$temp = exec('python /root/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/AdafruitDHT.py 22 4 | grep Temp=')` without any positive result.

and also

`$temp = exec('python /root/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples/AdafruitDHT.py &22 &4 | grep Temp=')` without any positive result.

Comment: I don't know why there would need to be `&` before the parameters. If the pipe works (which might not be the case, then putting `&` on the commandline will break things for sure. Remove the `| grep ....` see if you get something in PHP, if not make things simpler until they do. Then work from there checking with every step you take that things still work.

Comment: I'm not even getting the  
`Temp=19.9*  Humidity=41.5%`
on my site, even it is the result of the script.